# Angular img switch based on JSON property

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, image

So I am trying to have an icon be one or the other based on a property containing all or part of a word as shown in the code below.

If it contains "Health Care" or "Health Care .....", it grabs an image from one path, otherwise, it grabs from another. Seems I would embed this in ng-show, but cannot seem to get my syntax correct or something and not sure how I would combine the img tag.

Any of you know how this is done? The code I have now is:

```
<div class="col-md-2 oeCol">
    <img ng-show="benefit.benefitName('Health Care') ? src='ppt/assets/beneTiles/HealthCare.svg' : src='ppt/assets/beneTiles/DayCareFSA.svg' ">
</div>
```

I currently get no img at all.

Comment: it is ng-src not ng-show

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-md-2 oeCol">
    <img ng-src="{{benefit.benefitName('Health Care') ? 'ppt/assets/beneTiles/HealthCare.svg' : 'ppt/assets/beneTiles/DayCareFSA.svg'}}">
</div>
```

use `ng-src` and only specify the path, not the `src=...`, and I think it needs double curlies (`{{...}}`) to so it executes expression

Comment: Good thinking there Billy, hadn't thought of ng-src. That said, it seems it should work exactly as you have it, but it is not. Any other ideas?

Comment: Alright, what was needed here was that I need this "benefit.benefitName('Health Care')" to be "benefit.benefitName=='Health Care' " as the other way made it as if calling a function.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-show` only returns a boolean indicating if the node should display or not. Thus your `src` attribute contained in the `ng-show` just gets swallowed as part of the boolean check. You should be able to try `ng-src` and output your path there to display an image. Ideally, the logic for switching the src would be extracted out of the view and into a controller (or directive). However, if not you could also add two `<img>` elements on the DOM each with an `ng-show/ng-hide` attribute indicating if they should display on the page or not (depending on the json property you indicated). This is just pseudocode but it would look something like:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
  <img ng-src="ctrl.source()" />
</div>
```

P.S. Check out what Billy Moon posted as far as checking the json property in the dom itself.

Hope that helps.